# Como incluir datas mesmo que não haja dados

Tags: mysql, sql

Preciso fazer uma consulta no banco onde conto quantos veículos passaram em um intervalo de datas.

O código que estou usando é esse:

```
select date(data),
count(if(axlNumber = 2, 1, null)) as eixos2,
count(if(axlNumber = 3, 1, null)) as eixos3,
count(if(axlNumber = 4, 1, null)) as eixos4,
count(if(axlNumber = 5, 1, null)) as eixos5,
count(if(axlNumber = 6, 1, null)) as eixos6,
count(if(axlNumber = 7, 1, null)) as eixos7,
count(if(axlNumber = 8, 1, null)) as eixos8,
count(if(axlNumber = 9, 1, null)) as eixos9 
from tb_vbv where date(data) between '2018/11/01' and '2019/02/28' and siteid = 20110 group by 1;
```

Mas ele me retorna apenas datas que contém dados, preciso que retorne todas as datas e 0 onde não há dados.

Comment: Pelo que entendi você quer toas as datas do intervalo independente delas existirem no banco de dados. Veja esta implementação da função generate_series, existente em outros SGBD, no MySQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870499/generate-series-equivalent-in-mysql e faça um outer join com sua tabela.

Comment: é isso mesmo! obrigado!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Experimente desta forma:

```
SELECT      V.DataV
        ,   IFNULL(COUNT(IF(axlNumber = 2, 1, NULL)), 0) AS eixos2
        ,   IFNULL(COUNT(IF(axlNumber = 3, 1, NULL)), 0) AS eixos3
        ,   IFNULL(COUNT(IF(axlNumber = 4, 1, NULL)), 0) AS eixos4
        ,   IFNULL(COUNT(IF(axlNumber = 5, 1, NULL)), 0) AS eixos5
        ,   IFNULL(COUNT(IF(axlNumber = 6, 1, NULL)), 0) AS eixos6
        ,   IFNULL(COUNT(IF(axlNumber = 7, 1, NULL)), 0) AS eixos7
        ,   IFNULL(COUNT(IF(axlNumber = 8, 1, NULL)), 0) AS eixos8
        ,   IFNULL(COUNT(IF(axlNumber = 9, 1, NULL)), 0) AS eixos9 
FROM    (
            SELECT  ADDDATE('1970-01-01', t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) AS DataV
            FROM        (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0
                    ,   (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1
                    ,   (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2
                    ,   (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3
                    ,   (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4
        ) V
LEFT JOIN   tb_vbv ON DATE(tb_vbv.data) = V.DataV
WHERE       V.DataV BETWEEN '2018/11/01' AND '2019/02/28' 
        AND tb_vbv.siteid = 20110
GROUP BY    1;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!

Aqui está falando que a coluna data é ambigua

Comment: Resposta editada! Query corrigida.

Answer (score 0):

Para campos nulos eu uso dessa forma `WHERE c.id_modelo_produto IS NULL OR c.id_modelo_produto IS NOT NULL ORDER BY c.id_componente DESC`

Comment: Entendi! Obrigado pela resposta!Mas saberia me dizer como colocar isso no meu codigo? Porque as colunas que estou buscando são funções e não colunas da tabela